# Attempt to creating a Bongard problem

Tags: pattern, bongard

Here's my attempt creating a Bongard problem. 
 *Find the rule that is correct on the left side, but not on the right side.*

[image: bongard]

[What is a Bongard problem?](http://www.foundalis.com/res/diss_research.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it:

> If you consider the dots as eyes and the line as a nose, then they are the faces which are not upside down (the mouth is below not above).

More precisely:

> If you draw a line connecting the two dots, the intersection with the original line is on the top-part (top 50%) of the line.